# Get return value of wp_insert_comment (comment ID)

Tags: comments

On WordPress [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment) it says that return value (integer) is The new comment's ID.

Any idea how to retrieve comment ID created by `wp_insert_comment` function?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE! What do you mean? You just said that the function returns the ID of created comment.

Comment: I would like to echo that ID, but I dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_insert_comment` is both a [hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_comment) and a [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_comment). Once a comment is left on your blog, this action hook will be triggered, allowing you to modify the comment.

A very simple example would be:

```
add_action('wp_insert_comment','my_function',100,2);

function my_function($comment_id, $comment_object) {
    // Now you have access to $comment_id, save it, print it, do whatever you want with it
}
```

If you attempt and add a comment by using `wp_insert_comment`, then this function will return the ID of the inserted comment after it's done:

```
function add_new_comment($input, $post_id, $author, $user_id){
    // Get the current time 
    $time = current_time('mysql');
    // Set the arguments
    $data = array(
        'comment_post_ID' => $post_id,
        'comment_author' => $author,
        'comment_author_email' => 'admin@admin.com',
        'comment_author_url' => 'URL HERE',
        'comment_content' => $input,
        'comment_type' => '',
        'comment_parent' => 0,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'comment_author_IP' => 'IP HERE',
        'comment_agent' => 'USER AGENT HERE',
        'comment_date' => $time,
        'comment_approved' => 1,
    );
    // Store the ID in a variable
    $id = wp_insert_comment($data);
    // Return the ID
    return $id;
}
```

Now, if you call the `add_new_comment()` like the following, it will add a new comment and return its ID:

```
echo add_new_comment('My First Commnent', '123' , 'Admin' , '1');
```

Which is what you are looking for.

Comment: @user2127403 You're welcome mate.

Comment: You can achieve it without creating a function as well.
Like:
`$commentid = wp_insert_comment($data); echo $commentid ;`

Comment: @JitenGaikwad True. But how do you control the task if not wrapped in function? It will run every time the page is accessed.

Comment: @JackJohansson Correct. But it depends on where and how its used on page. If its going to use single time and need to access on page every time we can use without function. If we need to use it at different places and in certain conditions we can use function to avoid code rewriting.